# What is the best way to do GUIs in Clojure?

Tags: java, user-interface, lisp, clojure

What is the best way to do GUIs in [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure)?

Is there an example of some functional [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) or [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit) wrapper?
Or some integration with [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) declarative GUI description which could be easily wrapped to [s-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) using some macrology?

Any tutorials?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I will humbly suggest [Seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw).

[Here's a REPL-based tutorial](https://gist.github.com/1441520) that assumes no Java or Swing knowledge.

---

Seesaw's a lot like what @tomjen suggests. Here's "Hello, World":

```clj
(use 'seesaw.core)

(-> (frame :title "Hello"
       :content "Hello, Seesaw"
       :on-close :exit)
  pack!
  show!)
```

and here's @Abhijith and @dsm's example, translated pretty literally:

```clj
(ns seesaw-test.core
  (:use seesaw.core))

(defn handler
  [event]
  (alert event
    (str "<html>Hello from <b>Clojure</b>. Button "
      (.getActionCommand event) " clicked.")))

(-> (frame :title "Hello Swing" :on-close :exit
           :content (button :text "Click Me" :listen [:action handler]))
  pack!
  show!)
```

Comment: making Swing fun? They said it wasn't possible!

Comment: There's no need to be humble - you can be very proud of this one! +1!

Comment: -1: There's a bug in your code. It says "Hello, Seesaw" instead of "Hello, World". </Joke>

Comment: Really? Swing? Doesn't this limit the developer to the functionality Swing offers, just on a higher level of abstraction, if any? Does Clojure somehow make the applications look less outdated, or does it somehow improve all the areas in which Swing is weak? I am talking about bindings and MVC and all that "new" stuff, which Swing does now offer per se. Is it somehow fixed by language features of Clojure?

Comment: He chose to make a focused abstraction over Swing specifically.  Nothing wrong with that...

Answer (score 33):

Stuart Sierra recently published a series of blog posts on GUI-development with clojure (and swing). Start off here: http://stuartsierra.com/2010/01/02/first-steps-with-clojure-swing

Answer (score 17):

If you want to do GUI programming I'd point to [Temperature Converter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming#Simple_GUI_:_Temperature_Converter) or [the ants colony](http://clojure.googlegroups.com/web/ants.clj).

Many things in Swing are done by sub-classing, particularly if you are creating custom components. For that there are two essential functions/macros: [proxy](http://clojure.org/api#toc383) and [gen-class](http://clojure.org/api#toc234).

Now I understand where you are going with the more Lispy way. I don't think there's anything like that yet. I would strongly advise against trying to build a grandiose GUI-building framework a-la [CLIM](http://www.cliki.net/CLIM), but to do something more Lispy: start writing your Swing application and abstract out your common patterns with macros. When doing that you may end up with a language to write your kind of GUIs, or maybe some very generic stuff that can be shared and grow.

One thing you lose when writing the GUIs in Clojure is the use of tools like Matisse. That can be a strong pointing to write some parts in Java (the GUI) and some parts in Clojure (the logic). Which actually makes sense as in the logic you'll be able to build a language for your kind of logic using macros and I think there's more to gain there than with the GUI. Obviously, it depends on your application.

Comment: Don't worry about loosing Mattisse. You can use the http://www.miglayout.com/, which is powerful enough that you can do the layouts by hand.

Comment: You can use Matisse with Clojure, because the code generated is just Java code which can be seamlessly accessed by Clojure. There is actually a tutorial for that somewhere...

Comment: I wonder when we get the first clojure-outputing GUI designer. Due to the homoiconicity, the generated code shouldn't even be bad!

Answer (score 16):

Nobody yet suggested it, so I will: Browser as UI platform.  You could write your app in Clojure, including an HTTP server and then develop the UI using anything from HTML to [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup), ClojureScript and any of the billions of JS libaries you need.  If you wanted consistent browser behaviour and "desktop app look'n'feel" you could [bundle chrome with your app](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/about_apps.html).

This seems to be how [Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/) is distributed.

Comment: this is great, but determining the proper port may be tricky on every client machine

Answer (score 14):

From this [page](http://blog.thinkrelevance.com/2008/8/12/java-next-2-java-interop):

```
(import '(javax.swing JFrame JButton JOptionPane)) ;'
(import '(java.awt.event ActionListener))          ;'

(let [frame (JFrame. "Hello Swing")
     button (JButton. "Click Me")]
 (.addActionListener button
   (proxy [ActionListener] []
     (actionPerformed [evt]
       (JOptionPane/showMessageDialog  nil,
          (str "<html>Hello from <b>Clojure</b>. Button "
               (.getActionCommand evt) " clicked.")))))

 (.. frame getContentPane (add button))

 (doto frame
   (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
   .pack
   (.setVisible true)))

print("code sample");
```

And, of course, it would be worth looking at the [interoperability](http://clojure.org/java_interop) section of clojure's website.

Comment: Yeah, I know you can fall back to using Swing directly, but I was askig if there is more lispy way of doing it.

Comment: Also note that in the more recent versions of closure you need to add a . in front of the member function calls in the todo block.

Answer (score 8):

There is a wrapper for MigLayout in clojure contrib. You can also  take a look at [this gist](http://gist.github.com/261140). I am basically putting up whatever code I am writing as I am learning swing/miglayout.

dsm's example re-written in a lispy way using contrib.swing-utils

```
(ns test
      (:import (javax.swing JButton JFrame))
      (:use (clojure.contrib
          [swing-utils :only (add-action-listener)])))

    (defn handler
      [event]
      (JOptionPane/showMessageDialog nil,
        (str "<html>Hello from <b>Clojure</b>. Button "
          (.getActionCommand event) " clicked.")))

    (let [ frame (JFrame. "Hello Swing") 
           button (JButton. "Click Me")  ]
      (add-action-listener button handler)
        (doto frame
          (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
          (.add button)
          (.pack)
          (.setVisible true)))
```

Answer (score 7):

I would rather go for clojurefx, it is a bit premature, but it does work and saves you time.

I started my GUI with seesaw and then tried another component in clojurefx.

I have finished both, and I am convinced that I am going to refactor the seesaw one to clojurefx.

After all, JavaFX is the way to go forward.

It feels lighter than seesaw. Or at least, writing it..

Bindings work, listeners work, most of the component work, otherwise, just use one of the macros to create a constructor for that particular case and job done. Or, if you find it difficult, write some methods in Java and ask for help to improve clojurefx.

The guy who wrote clojurefx is busy at the moment, but you can fork the project and do some fixes.

Comment: Has JavaFX solved the problems of not looking very native yet? Serious question, because when I first checked it out, it was a long time ago, and it looked less correct than Swing.

Answer (score 6):

There's been [talk on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/cd88c3d948ff6b4a) about a few Cells (a la [Kenny Tilton's Cells](http://smuglispweeny.blogspot.com/2008/02/cells-manifesto.html)) implementations.  It's a pretty neat way to do GUI programming.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another very basic swing wrapping example:

```
; time for some swing
(import '(javax.swing JFrame JTable JScrollPane))
(import '(javax.swing.table DefaultTableModel))

(let 
  [frame (JFrame. "Hello Swing")
    dm (DefaultTableModel.)
      table (JTable. dm)
        scroll (JScrollPane. table)]
  (doto dm
      (.setNumRows 30)
        (.setColumnCount 5))
  (.. frame getContentPane (add scroll))
    (doto frame
      (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE) 
        (.pack)
        (.setVisible true)))
```

Answer (score 3):

I asked myself the same question of writing a GUI in Clojure with Swing and came up with the library [signe](https://github.com/jonasseglare/signe)

It lets you use represent your domain model as a single Clojure data structure wrapped inside an atom.

See the examples [here](https://github.com/jonasseglare/signe/blob/master/src/signe/examples.clj).

Answer (score 2):

I've been developing a Java applet in which everything is written in Clojure except the applet code, which is written in Java.  The applet invokes the Clojure code's callbacks of init, paint, etc from java's hooks for those methods that are defined by the applet model.  So the code ends up being 99.999 percent Clojure and you don't have to think about the tiny Java piece at all for the most part.

There are some drawbacks to this approach, which I hope to discuss in more detail on the Clojure Google Group. I think the Clojure developers should include a native way of building applications.  Presently you can do whatever GUI stuff you like from the REPL, but if you want a deliverable GUI application, it is necessary to write some Java to call the Clojure code.  Also, it seems like the architecture of a Java Applet kind of forces you outside of Clojure's more idiomatic best practices, requiring you to use mutable state, etc.

But also, I am not very far along with Clojure yet and it might be the case that it is possible and I just haven't discovered how to do it correctly yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an official one, but personally I would take advantage of the fact that I am using one of the most powerful language in the world and just imagine what the perfect gui code would look like:

```
(form {:title :on-close dispose :x-size 500 :y-size 450}
  [(button {:text "Close" :id 5 :on-click #(System/exit 0) :align :bottom})
   (text-field {:text "" :on-change #(.println System/out (:value %)) :align :center})
   (combo-box {:text "Chose background colour" :on-change background-update-function
               :items valid-colours})])
```

Your idea would differ but this should hopefully the above gives you some idea.

Comment: Looks like groovy SwingBuilder dsl translated to Clojure.

Comment: @dev-er-dev

That is very possible, I have never used groovy, but great minds do thing alike :)

Answer (score 2):

My preferred Clojure UI environment uses [IO.js (Node for ES6)](https://iojs.org/en/) + [Electron (Container)](http://electron.atom.io/) + [Quiescent (ReactJS wrapper)](https://github.com/levand/quiescent).

Comment: This might be complex, but I still want to ask: Can you provide an example on how to get started with these pieces? Or describe which part of an application would be handled by which of those frameworks / libraries you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

So I didn't see Fn-Fx on this list, from Timothy Baldridge (halgiri). This is a Clojure library providing a functional abstraction over JavaFX.

It can be found on Github at https://github.com/halgari/fn-fx.

To use, make sure you are using a recent version of Java (1.8 90+) and add a dependency to the github repo by adding the following to your project.clj:

```
:plugins [[lein-git-deps "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"]]
:git-dependencies [["https://github.com/halgari/fn-fx.git"]]
```

I have tried it, and it works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure and SWT is the best approach for doing GUI(s).  Essentially, SWT is a plug and play style approach for developing software.

Comment: Can you provide a link or an example? I'd be interested but have no idea of how to begin.

Comment: Carl, second that. A good tutorial on how to write Eclipse plugins using clojure would be rather nice.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are hinting for classical desktop solutions, but web fits quite well with clojure. I've written a complete audio application where everything is hooked up so that if you add music to the audio folder it is reflected in the web UI. Just saying that Desktop application isn't the only way :)

Answer (score 1):

**[cljfx](https://openjfx.io/)** is described as a

> Declarative, functional and extensible wrapper of JavaFX inspired by better parts of react and re-frame

and [JavaFx](https://openjfx.io/) as

> ... an open source, next generation client application platform for desktop, mobile and embedded systems built on Java. It is a collaborative effort by many individuals and companies with the goal of producing a modern, efficient, and fully featured toolkit for developing rich client applications.

Its creator uses it to build [reveal](https://vlaaad.github.io/reveal/), and a  [hackernews demo](https://github.com/cljfx/hn) that features various capabilities and some bundling for multiple OSs via [jpackage](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343).

You can get Clojure REPL-driven development with this by leveraging JavaFX to build UIs for desktop, mobile, and web.