# Simple GUI Toolkits For Use With Clojure

Tags: java, user-interface, clojure

The long and short of this question is which GUI tool kits create very simple UIs and are easy to use work with Clojure? Here are further details to narrow down my question.

I want to create very simple GUI applications that will run on Windows, without investing in a huge GUI design effort.

For example, our personnel department gets an insurance bill from our vendor for a number of subscribers and wants to audit that information against what their local insurance application thinks the subscribers are.

I would like to write these applications in Clojure, and also take advantage of simple GUI packages.

Which is the simplest tool that can be  used with Clojure to create a primitive UI? By primitive UI I mean something like an old Windows 3.1 (16-bit) modal dialog box.

Comment: Clojure can use Swing ya? Try any of the Swing design tools yet?

Comment: Thanks. I have heard of swing.

Comment: Of possible interest: [What is the best way to do GUIs in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/233171/420055)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about using SEESAW https://github.com/daveray/seesaw

That allow you to use the SWING standard widgets in Clojure

Comment: That actually looks a bit better than using swing directly.

Comment: I'm extremely biased, but it's actually *way* better than using Swing directly :)

Comment: There are some great examples on Julian Gamble's website: http://juliangamble.com/blog/